# Resize a Listbox inside a LabelFrame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I m trying to get the user to select a file via a Browse button, get the file path and display the filename in a Listbox for the user to see which file he has chosen.

My problem is that i want the Listbox widget to have height=3 rows.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

mainw=Tk()
fer1=LabelFrame(mainw,text='Something')
fer1.grid(row=0,columnspan=10,padx=5,pady=5,rowspan=3)
list=tk.Listbox(fer1)
list.grid=(row=0,column=columnspan=9,padx=5,pady=5,rowspan=3)

button=tk.Button(mainw,text="Browse")
button.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

mainw.mainloop()
```

Doesnt really matter what you change, it wont make the LISTBOX item less thn 10rows high. Is there any way to do this? Thx

Comment: that code has some syntax errors in it, making it unrunnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default height of a row using `grid` is zero. You can have the widget span a million rows and it's height will be the same as if it spans a single row, unless those other rows have something in them.

If you want a listbox to have three rows, you simply need to configure it that way with the `height` option:

```
list=tk.Listbox(fer1, height=3)
```

Of course, `pack`, `place` and `grid` options can cause it to grow or shrink, but setting the height this way establishes the preferred size.